# Strings being converted to unicode escape codes when not desired

Tags: python

In code I'm creating a string like this:

```
header_info = """
      <table style="border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse">
      <tr>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Validity</th>
        <th>Int/Ext</th>
        <th>Domains</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Confidence</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
"""
```

Then creating row like this:

```
row_data += f"<tr><td>{ip}</td><td>{valid}</td><td>{intext}</td><td>{domains}</td><td>{severity}</td><td>{conf}</td><td>{category}</td><td>{country}</td></tr>\n"
```

The data for the variables ip, intext, domains, etc comes from an external system (i.e. I get it from a third party REST API that I assign to the variables using `.decode('utf-8')`).

I then return a string back combining the header with the row data (i.e. header_info+row_data).

Most of the time it is ok and I get back the string that looks just like the html, however, sometimes I'm getting it back as unicode, e.g. as below.

I suspect the problem is the incoming data may be encoded differently, but I don't know how to fix it other than my call to decode.

Just to clarify, this python code is running inside a basic python Docker image. The Docker image is actually instantiated and called by an integration engine (XSOAR, but I don't think knowledge of this is required) and returned to me by this engine, so I have no idea what goes on 'inside' the integration engine that is mangling my data. I was just hoping this is an obvious character set conversion error.

Example when it doesn't work, when instead of the usual html human readable I get unicode escape characters:

"\u003ctable style="border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse"\u003e\n \u003ctr\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eIP\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eValidity\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eInt/Ext\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eDomains\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eSeverity\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eConfidence\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eCategory\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003cth\u003eCountry\u003c/th\u003e\n \u003c/tr\u003e\n \u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd\u003e100.64.0.2\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eNo data found\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eExternal\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eUnknown Domain '100.64.0.2'\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003eNo country supplied\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e ......"

Comment: "I then return a string back combining the header with the row data (i.e. header_info+row_data)." Return it to where? "Most of the time it is ok and I get back the string that looks just like the html, however, sometimes I'm getting it back as unicode" Getting it back where? How do you view this result? It's not actually clear what your overall process is. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You describe using some integration engine, but I can't visualize *how* you do so.

Comment: Also: is this a string representation of the data, or what you actually see? What context are you seeing it in - a debugger? HTML source output? The point is - does the string actually contain backslashes followed by lowercase `u`s etc., or is it simply displaying the representation of a string in a non-standard way?

Comment: Also: *what is different* about the times where you see the "weird" output and the times where you see "normal" output? Can you actually consistently reproduce the problem?

Comment: If an answer to "how do I translate unicode escapes in a string ?" is good enough, then you should start by putting that into a search engine. I suspect you will find many duplicate Stack Overflow questions, or near enough to duplicate for your purposes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, i figured I'd get a 'minimum reproducible'  response, I was hoping there was something I was missing when manipulating text that is unicode :) 

I've converted the unicode characters and it's just plain text, so something is converting this string to the escape characters. So no I can't reproduce it consistently. Regarding other question, the problem is this is a script running inside an automation/workflow engine and the automation engine opens up and runs my code then returns back what the code outputs into the workflow system.

Comment: *All* text "is unicode".